# Make view scroll out of the window (Like Twitter profile layout) android xml layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, xml-layout

I want to have twitter-profile-like layout. My xml is as follows :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    style="@style/app_bar_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_cover_height"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/stroked_background_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile_text"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
                android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_photo_half_size"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_verified"
                android:text="User Name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_drawer_user_level"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_level_text_height"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_level_text_margin_top"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Level: 10 | Points: 95"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Overline"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_user_photo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_photo_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_photo_size"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_photo_margin_top"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_profile_photo" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/toolbar_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_user_about"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Tell others about yourself, who are you, what do you want to do out ther my dear friend, just talk."
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_drawer_user_institute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_institute"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Zagazig Univerity, Faculty Of Science, First Year"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_drawer_user_join_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_time"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Joined 21 march 2020"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_drawer_user_followers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/text_background_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="111 Followers"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_drawer_user_following"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/text_background_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="90 Following"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="auto" />

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

So, what changes should I make so that the linear layout with id 'layout_info' will scroll out of window ? I tried to put it inside the collapsing toolbar, It would scroll out but that's not how I want it to be because toolbar shows after everything is scrolled out, I want it to appear earlier. I also tried to put inside 'NestedScrollView' but It didn't work.

Comment: maybe this library helps: https://github.com/SIMMORSAL/ConcealerNestedScrollView-ConcealerRecyclerView

Comment: I think It's much simpler than using an external library